# make all gtk labels selectable

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

Is there a way to set the default value for weather gtk_labels are selectable to true, so the user can select anything on my app? I know of a way to set it to true for one label using the `gtk_label_set_selectable(label, bool)` function, but I wanted to set a default value to true rather than false so that I don't have to do this for every label. I am writing the app in c using gtk3, but i would also accept questions that provide help regarding other programming languages because I can usually map them to their C equivelant using the documentation. Please don't try to report the post because I didn't provide enough information; this is all the info you need. If you need more info, request it in the comments.

Comment: You should have provided a minimal code together with the Question.

Comment: In other language you can easily inherit from GtkLabel and override it's selectable properties. In C you can but it's way more complicated. I guess you can do it with template. https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.Widget.html#building-composite-widgets-from-template-xml